# Datastage Oracle Importing Table

Tags: datastage

I have a error when i use datastage connect to Oracle and import the table definition. Below is the detailed situation.

```
enviroment:
OS：AIX6.1，64bit，power6 processor, LANG=en_US
Data Stage Version：8.5
```

Installation profile
three tiers install on same machine, repository use DB2 (default).
Oracle Client 11.2 (64bit) also install on this machine, I can use SQLPLUS connect to Oracle server (11.2, 64bit, AL32UTF8) on another machine.

```
"dsenv" setting
add "/oracle/product/11.2.0-64/lib" to the "LIBPATH"
add "export TNS_ADMIN=/oracle/product/11.2.0-64/network/admin"
```

Problem
1. I use Oracle Connector(parallel) create a Link, then use this Link import Metadata, when i press Test connection, there is a dialog with `"The OCI function OraOCIEnvNlsCreate:OCI_UTF16ID returned status -1.` Error code: `NULL`, Error message: `NULL`" popup, `and the connection failed.`

2. I use Oracle Enterprise(parallel) create a Link, then use it import Metadata, when i click Ellipsis button list all the tables in target database, there is a dialog with "cannot get list of table names from database" popup, after I click OK on this dialog, the detail error message popup.

12:37:21(002)  Unable to access database oracleLibrary orchoracle could not be loaded; Could not load "orchoracle": 
0509-022 Cannot load module /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSComponents/bin/orchoracle.o.
0509-150 Dependent module /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSComponents/bin/libclntsh.so could not be loaded.
0509-103 The module has an invalid magic number.
0509-022 Cannot load module /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSComponents/bin/orchoracle.o.
0509-150 Dependent module /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSComponents/bin/orchoracle.o could not be loaded.

from the message I found the DS search some files in DSCompoments/bin, but these files are in the oracle bin directory. I can't find the error in dsenv file, so i copied these files into DSComponents/bin, this time the error message changed to "OCI_ERROR: Bad Oracle environment".
I am not sure which enviroment variable I missed, please tell me.

3. I use Oracle OCI(Server) create a Link and import a table, it works fine.

**So, my question is why I can't use the Oracle Connector and Oracle Enterprise to connect the Oracle. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes the PATH variable needs to be set to $ORACLE_HOME/bin. Adding this variable to the dsenv file and recycling all services fixed the Oracle COnnector issue for us. It is required to be added to the dsenv file and recycling ASBNode and datastage is also required. Here are the directives needed in the dsenv file to use Oracle Connector :(eg is from our system AIX 6.1 , datastage 8.5 connecting to Oracle 11g Enterprise)

We also added the following :
TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/product/11.1.0/client_1/network/admin; export TNS_ADMIN